# Search by LIKE not working in database vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, local-database

For some reason the like is not working, for example is the name where Jason and I search for 'Ja', 'jason' should show up it does not. Is my code faulty? This is in a local database, maybe that helps?

```
 Private Sub BTN_Search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_Search.Click
    'If txtbox is blank then show all records, else do the search by first name.
    If TBX_Search.Text = "" Then
        DoctorsDataGridView.DataSource = Me.RecordsDataSet.Doctors.Select("FirstName LIKE'" & "%" & "'")
    Else
        DoctorsDataGridView.DataSource = Me.RecordsDataSet.Doctors.Select("FirstName LIKE'" & TBX_Search.Text & "'")
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that this code works? Assigning a DataRow array as a DataSource for a DataGridView doesn't seems to be right. Do you see the content of your row when you have the search text empty?

Comment: Yes I do, there is no issue with that side of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Private Sub BTN_Search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_Search.Click
      'If txtbox is blank then show all records, else do the search by first name.
      If TBX_Search.Text = "" Then
           DoctorsDataGridView.DataSource = Me.RecordsDataSet.Doctors.Select("FirstName LIKE '%'")
      Else
           DoctorsDataGridView.DataSource = Me.RecordsDataSet.Doctors.Select("FirstName LIKE '%" & TBX_Search.Text & "%'")
      End If
 End Sub
```

In your code you tell the database to fetch articles matching **Ja** instead of looking for **Ja%** (and anything behind it)

- Add the **%** before your searchstring to allow results with anything in front of the **Ja**
- Add the **%** after your searchstring to allow results with anything after the **Ja**
- Add them both before and after the searchstring to match any result with the term **Ja** in it

Answer (score 1):

`%` indicates the partial or missing part(s), you still need it (for your case) at the end.

`DoctorsDataGridView.DataSource = Me.RecordsDataSet.Doctors.Select("FirstName LIKE'" & TBX_Search.Text & "%'")`

Also, google "SQL injection", the above code is asking for trouble.

Comment: No, the Select method is not affected by Sql Injection. It doesn't work that way with an in memory object like a DataTable. By the way I would also suggest to remove completely the filter expression in the first case. A Select without a filter returns all rows

Comment: @Steve >You are correct on the filter expression, I should have seen that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need the wildcard on the Else logic:

> DoctorsDataGridView.DataSource =
>   Me.RecordsDataSet.Doctors.Select("FirstName LIKE'" & TBX_Search.Text &
>   "%'")

This is the logic for "starts with" text.